# Cannot use FCL with ROS

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, fcl, octree, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I am trying to use FCL with an Octree to perform obstacle detection. I downloaded the source code of FCL from github and performed the installation instructions:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
```

This, I think, created a folder in usr/local/include/fcl with the installed library inside.

Now it was required to access it with ROS. For that, I added:

```
find_package(fcl REQUIRED)
${fcl_INCLUDE_DIRS}
target_link_libraries(obstacleDetection ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OCTOMAP_LIBRARIES} ${fcl_LIBRARY_DIRS} ${FCL_LIBRARIES})
```

to my CMakeLists.txt file.

It compiles with *catkin_make*, but when I add

```
#include "fcl/shape/geometric_shapes.h"
```

, for example, to my *obstacleDetection.h*, it shows a lot of errors, such as:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/cstdint:35:0,
             from /usr/include/fcl/data_types.h:42,
             from /usr/include/fcl/math/vec_3f.h:42,
             from /usr/include/fcl/BV/AABB.h:42,
             from /usr/include/fcl/collision_object.h:43,
             from /usr/include/fcl/shape/geometric_shapes.h:42,
             from /home/jpdelopes/ros_ws/src/prjc/src/../include/PrecisionAgriculture/obstacleDetection.h:27,
             from /home/jpdelopes/ros_ws/src/prjc/src/obstacleDetection.cpp:6:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
#error This file requires compiler and library support \
(...)
/usr/include/fcl/data_types.h:48:14: error: ‘int64_t’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
typedef std::int64_t  FCL_INT64;
(...)
In file included from /usr/include/fcl/collision_object.h:44:0,
             from /usr/include/fcl/shape/geometric_shapes.h:42,
             from /home/jpdelopes/ros_ws/src/prjc/src/../include/PrecisionAgriculture/obstacleDetection.h:27,
             from /home/jpdelopes/ros_ws/src/prjc/src/obstacleDetection.cpp:6:
/usr/include/fcl/math/transform.h:185:8: error: ‘mutex’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
std::mutex lock_;
```

Which are three different errors. I think that the FCL library is detected, right? I do not know how to solve these errors.

PS: I think that I have installed all of the FCL library dependencies.

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/291649/cannot-use-fcl-with-ros/) by [jpde.lopes](https://answers.ros.org/users/34263/jpde.lopes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 64 on 2018-05-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
> ```

Newer FCL versions require [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) support enabled. That is also what the error states.

You'll have to do this in the `CMakeLists.txt` of *your* package.

Some larger projects (such as MoveIt fi) do this by adding the following somewhere at the top of `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_definitions(-std=c++11)
```

Note that this should also be part already of your `CMakeLists.txt`, but commented.

---

Edit:

> Now it was required to access it with ROS. For that, I added:

and just a quick note: none of this is ROS-specific. I keep repeating that in every question that deals with this kind of topic, but this is all basic CMake. The fact that you're creating a ROS package, and that you use `catkin_make` to build it does not change that.

You would have to do the exact same thing if you weren't using ROS.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jpde.lopes](https://answers.ros.org/users/34263/jpde.lopes/) on 2018-05-18**:
Thank you for your answer. I will try the first part now.
Regarding the cmake part, thanks for the clarification.

**Comment by [jpde.lopes](https://answers.ros.org/users/34263/jpde.lopes/) on 2018-05-18**:
Thank you! It solved the error regarding the C++11.